# Does deleting Elasticsearch index (or all indecies) delete the actual data as well?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to ElasticSearch, and need to know if deleting index/mapping deletes all the actual data as well? And if yes, is there a way to recover the data?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Deleting an index deletes the index as well as data.
There's no way to delete a mapping on elastic search. You can update mapping using PUT api for mapping.

To delete an index, either use DELETE in Sense.

```
DELETE index_name
```

Sometimes(eg- AWS ES as service), that doesn't work where you can use the curl command to delete the index/documents.

```
curl -XDELETE 'hostname:port/index_name?pretty'
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which version of Elasticsearch you are using. Till 1.7, deleting mapping deletes the documents also. 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/indices-delete-mapping.html

From 2.0 onwards, you cannot delete a mapping directly. You can only delete the index. 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/indices-delete-mapping.html

As far as I know it is not possible to recover docs once the index / mapping is deleted. (Although I am not a 100% sure).

Comment: Yes, deleting the index, deletes all the data in that index. The only recovery method is if you have an ES snapshot (or other backup to recreate the index, like the original data).